# Pandas.Series.Str.Find mixed in with x in a list

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, attributeerror

Good afternoon!

Long story short, I'm trying to do sentiment analysis on certain features of phones based on a review dataset. I'm coordinating this with a .loc function and it's worked before but this is a certain list instead of a string. I'm trying to link this to any x within a list, with the x being a list.

Here's what I have:

```
Battery = ['battery', 'charge', 'juice', 'talk time', 'hours', 'minutes']
batt = apple['Reviews'].str.lower().str.find(x in Battery)!=-1
```

The error returned is:

`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values.`

I did it this way because it did not like when I just put Battery instead of x in Battery.

Any suggestions? Thanks again!

The expected output would be, if I ran the variable assigned, are all rows that have any of the keywords. (The x within Battery). So any rows with anything like charge, juice, etc. would pop up.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there (small) sample input and expected output?

Comment: I edited to include the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: I mean put there sample (small) input dataframe (in text format, so we can copy-paste it) and also output dataframe (also in text format).

Comment: I'm on a different computer. I can't really do right now unfortunately.

Comment: The columns are Item #, Brand, Model, Reviews, Price, Rating, Data, Verified, Review Title, Review, Helpful.

The first row says B07RT1X4FJ, Apple, AppleiPhoneXS 256 GB, Gray For AT&T (Renewed), 198, 0.00, 5. 2019-07-20, Verified, Basically Perfect and Brand New, I was a little bit scared of my purchase, 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `apple['Review']` is just a column of strings, you can check [**`str.contains()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Given these `Battery` and `apple`:

```py
Battery = ['battery', 'charge', 'juice', 'talk time', 'hours', 'minutes']
apple = pd.DataFrame({'Review': ['abc battery xyz', 'foo bar', 'orange juice bar', 'talk time']})

#              Review
# 0   abc battery xyz
# 1           foo bar
# 2  orange juice bar
# 3         talk time
```

This would be the `batt` output:

```py
batt = apple[apple['Review'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(Battery))]

#              Review
# 0   abc battery xyz
# 2  orange juice bar
# 3         talk time
```

---

<s>If `apple['Review']` is a column of lists, you can first join them with [**`str.join(' ')`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) before checking [**`str.contains()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):</s>

```py
batt = apple[apple['Review'].str.join(' ').str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(Battery))]
```

Comment: apple['Reviews'] is a series containing only strings so it makes me believe it's the second, but to check, this will use any item that's in the list Battery, correct?

Comment: I also just tried both lines of codes and it looks like I have the same error. If I can't get on the internet fast enough, I'll either update when I get it up or I'll resubmit it.

Comment: Here's an image.

Comment: @ESarousi The `Reviews` column is a numeric rating. `Review` (without `s`) is the column with strings. The code should work if you replace `Reviews` with `Review`.

Comment: Ah, you're completely right! Thank goodness. That was a silly error on my end. Thank you!